# Minimizing FSM (Mealy)

Tags: state-machine, fsm, minimization

My exam is tomorrow and I need your help to understand what I'm doing wrong, My book had the following question:

Design a **minimal** FSM (Mealy) that outputs 1 iff u(t)-v(t)=3n for some natural n, where:

u(t) is the number of 1 digits until now, and v(t) is the number of 0 digits received.

The book shows an answer using only 3 Staes, I didn't understand how is this possible so I went to write my own machine and trying to minimize it to see if I get the same thing.

I declared 5 states:

- T - number of zeros is equal to number of ones.
- 0+ - number of zeros is bigger than number of ones by 1.
- 1+ - number of ones is bigger than number of zeroes by 1.
- 0++ - number of zeros is bigger than number of ones by 2.
- 1++ - number of ones is bigger than number of zeroes by 2.

So my table looks like:

```
Current State | x=0,z | x=1,z
T               0+,0    1+,0
1+              T,0     1++,0
1++             1+,0    T,1
0+              0++,0   T,0
0++             T,1     0+,0
```

But when I minimize it I get:

```
P0 = (T,1+,1++,0+,0++)
P1 = (0++)(1++)(T,1+,0+)
p2 = (0++)(1++)(T)(1+)(0+)
```

which means the states can't be minimized.

Comment: please let me know if anything isn't clear

Comment: How is this related to assembly or RISC-V?